# increase attribute onclick in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to increase an attribute onclick in jquery, 1 at a time.

Let's say I have this button, and it's the only `.new-rcc` on the page:

```
<a class="new-rcc" data-attr="1" href="#"><span>Button &raquo;</span></a>
```

Each time the button is clicked, I need to increase the `data-attr` by 1, so it would just increase from 1 to 2 to 3 to 4, etc.

I tried doing something like this:

```
var showthese = $('.new-rcc').prop('data-attr');
$('.new-rcc').click(function(){
    var showtotal = showthese++;
    $(this).prop('data-attr', showtotal);
    return false;
});
```

But it doesn't seem to want to work?

Comment: I suggest using `.data('attr')` instead of `.prop('data-attr')`. There are various reasons for it, but mainly because if you attach "data-attr" as an attribute, jQuery won't recognize it, only if it's attached by `.data()`, pending your jQuery version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

data attributes aren't properties, so you have to use `attr()` and not `prop()` :

```
var showthese = $('.new-rcc').data('attr');
$('.new-rcc').click(function(){
    showthese++;
    $(this).attr('data-attr', showthese);
    return false;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4p2Q9/)

note that you can use `data()` to get the value, but setting the value with `data()` doesn't really update the attribute, it's just stored internally by jQuery.

Comment: Herp.. of course lol. I knew it had to be simple! I'll accept when it lets me :)

Answer (score 2):

The value of the expression `showthese++` is *original* value of `showthese`.

You want the pre-increment operator (`++showthese`), which evaluates to the resulting value.